# Setting jquery.animate CSS properties to values stored in the DOM element using $(this).data

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

```
#me {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    width:150px;
    padding: 5px;
    position: relative;
}

<div id='me'>Here we go</div>
```

OK, I'm trying to set CSS properties of the $.animate method to values stored in the DOM element using the $.data method. Now this works

```
$('#me').data().moveto = 50;
$('#me').animate({ left: '+=' + $('#me').data('moveto') }, 2000, function() {
    $(this).text('Finished: '+$(this).data('moveto'));
});
```

But this doesn't

```
$('#me').data().moveto = 50;
$('#me').animate({ left: '+=' + $(this).data('moveto') }, 2000, function() {
    $(this).text('Finished: '+$(this).data('moveto'));
});
```

Nothing happens. Now should this second method not work?

And in both cases the this is recognised and the text is set to Finished: 50.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

In here:

```
$('div').animate({ left: '+=' + $(this).data('moveto') }, 2000);
```

the `this` is going to be the same `this` that it was outside the function call so that is equivalent to this:

```
var self = this;
$('div').animate({ left: '+=' + $(self).data('moveto') }, 2000);
```

and `self` probably isn't the `<div>` you're looking for so `$(this).data('moveto')` returns `undefined` and you end trying to do:

```
$('div').animate({ left: '+=' }, 2000);
```

which doesn't do anything useful. Try this example and you should see what's going on:

> http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/NXDKB/

Also, you're probably better off doing:

```
$('#me').data('moveto', 50);
```

instead of:

```
$('#me').data().moveto = 50;
```

As you found in the docs (thank's for the heads up on that BTW), `$x.data()` will return the data object but interesting things might happen if `$x` matches more than one DOM element.

Comment: Well the div selector was just used as an example. I have stored a value on the DOM element using the data method and wish to access it inside the animation function where the this should refer to the element. Is that not correct? Also not sure what you mean by "self probably isn't the <div> you're looking".

Comment: @Jack: it looks like you're assuming that the `$(this)` inside the `animate` call will be the same as the `$('div')` that you're calling `animate` on; in general it won't be.

Comment: Hmmm, OK I edited my question, added an id to the specific div I'm working with. So, will the this inside the animate call not refer to that particular element? I was sure it should. No?

Comment: @Jack: No, it will still behave the same as my `var self...` example. `this` inside the argument list is exactly the same as `this` outside the argument list. The arguments are evaluated before the the function is called.

Comment: But surely the this outside the argument call IS the element I want, the only one inside the wrapped set?

Comment: @Jack: You need to provide an example of the context in which your `animate` is being used, an isolated fragment isn't enough to say what `this` is going to be. You're also using `.data` improperly. The `this` inside the callback functions **is** (by design) the thing you called `animate` on but that's immaterial to what `this` is when the argument list is evaluated.

Comment: @Jack: Click the button on this fiddle and maybe you'll see what I'm talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/NXDKB/

Comment: Ah OK, so the this inside the animate function refers to the JQuery object, which was my mistake. That right?

Comment: Also, if you look here http://api.jquery.com/data/ it says calling .data() returns the various data values stored on that element as an object: `$('body').data(); // {foo: 52, bar: { myType: 'test', count: 40 }}`

Comment: OK, so I suppose to get it to work I just rewrite the code to animate each element seperately inside an each function `$('div').each(function() {
 $(this).animate({ left: '+=' + $(this).data('moveto') }, 2000);
});`

Comment: @Jack: Yeah, `this` in the argument list is the `this` outside the argument list not the `this` that would be in the `animate` callback. Nice find on the `.data()` thing, I'll fix up my comments on that but I'd still recommend using `.data(k,v)` to set things. I think your `$('div').each(...` approach is what you're after.